# mysql - count records after ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, join, select, sql-order-by

I have the code to count records but unable to add order by before it.

Two tables are joined and I added the code to count records. The issue is that I want to first ORDER BY SN and assign cnt after?

My code is:

**Tables**

```
 create table rot (
            code int(10) primary key,
            PN varchar(10) not null,
        SN varchar(10) not null,
            LocID int(10) not null);

    insert into rot values (1,'T1','T1SN1','1');
    insert into rot values (2,'A1','A1SN1','2');
    insert into rot values (3,'J1','J1SN1','3');
    insert into rot values (4,'A2','A2SN1','1');
    insert into rot values (5,'J2','J2SN1','2');
    insert into rot values (6,'A3','A3SN1','3');
    insert into rot values (7,'J3','J3SN1','4');
    insert into rot values (8,'T1','T1SN2','5');
    insert into rot values (9,'A1','A1SN2','1');
    insert into rot values (10,'J2','J2SN2','3');
    insert into rot values (11,'J2','J2SN3','4');
    insert into rot values (12,'A1','A1SN3','3');
    insert into rot values (13,'J2','J2SN4','5');

    create table loc(
        code1 int(10) primary key,
        LocVar varchar(10) not null);

    insert into loc values (1,'AAA');
    insert into loc values (2,'BBB');
    insert into loc values (3,'CCC');
    insert into loc values (4,'DDD');
    insert into loc values (5,'EEE');
```

**Cnt code:**

```
SELECT * FROM rot
JOIN loc ON rot.code = loc.code1

JOIN (
            SELECT t1.code, count(*) cnt FROM (
                SELECT distinct code
                FROM rot ts1 
            JOIN loc tx1 ON ts1.code = tx1.code1 

) t1 
JOIN (
    SELECT distinct code
                FROM rot ts2
            JOIN loc tx2 ON ts2.code = tx2.code1

    ) t2 on t1.code <= t2.code 
    group by t1.code 

) tt ON rot.code = tt.code
```

**Results:**

```
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+
| code | PN | SN    | LocID | code1 | LocVar | code | cnt |
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+
|    2 | A1 | A1SN1 |     2 |     2 | BBB    |    2 |   4 |
|    4 | A2 | A2SN1 |     1 |     4 | DDD    |    4 |   2 |
|    3 | J1 | J1SN1 |     3 |     3 | CCC    |    3 |   3 |
|    5 | J2 | J2SN1 |     2 |     5 | EEE    |    5 |   1 |
|    1 | T1 | T1SN1 |     1 |     1 | AAA    |    1 |   5 |
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+
```

**Desired results**

```
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+
| code | PN | SN    | LocID | code1 | LocVar | code | cnt |
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+
|    2 | A1 | A1SN1 |     2 |     2 | BBB    |    2 |   1 |
|    4 | A2 | A2SN1 |     1 |     4 | DDD    |    4 |   2 |
|    3 | J1 | J1SN1 |     3 |     3 | CCC    |    3 |   3 |
|    5 | J2 | J2SN1 |     2 |     5 | EEE    |    5 |   4 |
|    1 | T1 | T1SN1 |     1 |     1 | AAA    |    1 |   5 |
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+-----+
```

I just wonder where to place ORDER BY? In my code I am unable to assign variables and the code must start with SELECT.

Comment: You want a sequence number, right? not really a count. There's no diffrence between Results and Desired results except the cnt column. But the row order hasnt changed at all. Confusing

Comment: what this count stands for here?
I mean which counts do you want from your data?

Can you please make your question more clear

Comment: I suggest a better explanation of your needs. In the **Results** table and the logic of the query you have made, the **cnt** column keep a counter of the number of codes that are greater or equal compared to the code value of the row. In other words, for example, code 2 is lower or equal than 2,3,4 and 5, so you store a 4 on **cnt** column. In the **Desired results** this has lost all sense, since you only save the position of the ordering on the **cnt** column.

Comment: I agree with D. Smania. Your count is what it is and it shouldn't change because of the sorting. Otherwise the counts do no longer match the corresponding SN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, and based on the commentary i have made to your question, that i will quote next:

> In the **Results** table and the logic of the query you have made, the
>   **cnt** column keep a counter of the number of codes that are greater or equal compared to the code value of the row. In other words, and
>   for example, code 2 is lower or equal than codes 2,3,4 and 5, so you
>   store a 4 on the **cnt** column. But, in the **Desired Results** this
>   has lost all sense, since you only save the position of the current
>   ordering on the **cnt** column.

Assuming you only need the order position by **SN** on the **cnt** column, you can try next solution that don't depend of MySQL 8.0 and do not use user-variables:

```
SELECT rot.*,
       loc.*,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM rot AS rot1
         INNER JOIN loc AS loc1 ON loc1.code1 = rot1.code
         WHERE rot1.SN <= rot.SN ) AS cnt
FROM
    rot
INNER JOIN
    loc ON loc.code1 = rot.code
ORDER BY
    rot.SN
```

Answer (score 8):

If MySQL 8.0 you could use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```
SELECT *, rot.code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SN) AS cnt
FROM rot
JOIN loc ON rot.code = loc.code1
ORDER BY SN;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86971a7c15eacb99c228bb76b0bf1c69)**

```
+-------+-----+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-----+
| code  | PN  |  SN    | LocID  | code1  | LocVar  | code  | cnt |
+-------+-----+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-----+
|    2  | A1  | A1SN1  |     2  |     2  | BBB     |    2  |   1 |
|    4  | A2  | A2SN1  |     1  |     4  | DDD     |    4  |   2 |
|    3  | J1  | J1SN1  |     3  |     3  | CCC     |    3  |   3 |
|    5  | J2  | J2SN1  |     2  |     5  | EEE     |    5  |   4 |
|    1  | T1  | T1SN1  |     1  |     1  | AAA     |    1  |   5 |
+-------+-----+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM rot
    JOIN loc ON rot.code = loc.code1
    JOIN (
        SELECT t1.code3, count(*) cnt
        FROM (
            SELECT distinct code as code3
            FROM rot ts1
            JOIN loc tx1 ON ts1.code = tx1.code1
        ) t1
        JOIN (
            SELECT distinct code
            FROM rot ts2
            JOIN loc tx2 ON ts2.code = tx2.code1
        ) t2 on t1.code3 <= t2.code group by t1.code3
    ) tt ON rot.code = tt.code3
)X
ORDER BY X.cnt ASC;
```

Comment: have you tested to conclude that it doesn't return desired results ?

Comment: Yes I have tested

Comment: @ Avinash - is not ordered by SN.

Comment: @Kalenji Do you want to order by SN?

Comment: Yes as per my original query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM rot JOIN loc ON rot.code = loc.code1 JOIN ( SELECT t1.code3, count(*) cnt FROM ( SELECT distinct code as code3 FROM rot ts1 JOIN loc tx1 ON ts1.code = tx1.code1 ) t1 JOIN ( SELECT distinct code FROM rot ts2 JOIN loc tx2 ON ts2.code = tx2.code1) t2 on t1.code3 <= t2.code group by t1.code3 ) tt ON rot.code = tt.code3)X ORDER BY X.SN ASC;



Try this

Answer (score 2):

As per given details above, You can get the desired result using below query:

```
SELECT code, PN,SN,LocID,code1,LocVar ,code, @row := @row + 1 AS cnt FROM (
SELECT  code, PN,SN,LocID,code1,LocVar
FROM rot 
JOIN loc 
ON code=code1
ORDER BY SN) tab, (SELECT @row := 0) r;
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+------+
| CODE | PN | SN    | LocID | code1 | LocVar | CODE | cnt  |
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+------+
|    2 | A1 | A1SN1 |     2 |     2 | BBB    |    2 |    1 |
|    4 | A2 | A2SN1 |     1 |     4 | DDD    |    4 |    2 |
|    3 | J1 | J1SN1 |     3 |     3 | CCC    |    3 |    3 |
|    5 | J2 | J2SN1 |     2 |     5 | EEE    |    5 |    4 |
|    1 | T1 | T1SN1 |     1 |     1 | AAA    |    1 |    5 |
+------+----+-------+-------+-------+--------+------+------+
```

Hope you want to achieve this through your query. Please check and enjoy :) !

Comment: As per original query - I can not use variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code, PN, SN, LocID, code1, LocVar, code, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as cnt FROM rot
JOIN loc ON rot.code = loc.code1
JOIN (
    SELECT distinct code
                FROM rot ts2
            JOIN loc tx2 ON ts2.code = tx2.code1

    ) t2 on t1.code <= t2.code 
    group by loc.code1 
    order by rot.SN;
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: As per original query - I can not use variables.

Comment: Why you could not use variables...?